# Is there a difference between the following 2 commands

Tags: telerik, nativescript

`npm i nativescript-telerik-ui` and `tns plugin add nativescript-telerik-ui`.

I'm also looking for a release notes for the telerik ui package - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` (or `npm i`) only installs the module. If you use it, make sure to set the `--save` flag as that would save you project's dependency on the module in the package.json.

`tns plugin add` actually saves the dependency for you, and does a couple of additional things: resolve additional dependencies the plugin has, run a partial prepare, etc. There's an elaborate explanation of the installation specifics in the NativeScript plugins documentation [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins#installation-specifics).+

> I'm also looking for a release notes for the telerik ui package - any help appreciated.

You can find the UI for NativeScript release notes in the [official docs](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/release-notes).

Answer (score 0):

The installation of a NativeScript plugin mimics the installation of an npm package. The NativeScript CLI downloads the plugin from npm and adds the plugin to the node_modules folder in the root of your project. During this process, the NativeScript CLI adds the plugin to your project’s root package.json file and also resolves the plugin’s dependencies (if any).

https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/plugins#installing-plugins